# ggplot2 heatmap layout

Tags: r, layout, ggplot2, heatmap

consider the following heatmap:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rep(letters[1:10],10), b=rep(letters[1:10], each=10), c=sample(2,100, replace=TRUE))
ggplot(df, aes(a, b)) + geom_tile(aes(fill= c))
```

As it can be seen from the plot, between the segments of the x-axis, there are white vertical lines separating the values of the x-axis. Is it somehow possible to add such white horizontal lines to separate the segments of the y-axis like the ones can be seen on the second plot here:

http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/

Also, is it possible to increase the margin of the grey background to have it as big as in the second plot of the above link?

Comment: The answer is the link you point `geom_tile(aes(fill = c), colour = white)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're still looking for an answer:

In the comment above, `white` needs to be enclosed in quotes.

To increase the size of the gray border, use `expand` inside `scale_x_...()` and `scale_y_...()` functions.  "Expand" is a two element vector: the first element is a multiplicative constant, the second element is an additive constant. The constants ensure that data points are plotted some distance away from the axes. When both are set to 0, there is no border.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a=rep(letters[1:10],10), b=rep(letters[1:10], each=10), c=sample(2,100, replace=TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(a, b)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = c), colour = "white") +
   scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 1)) + scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your example. Works great for my real data. I was still looking but kind of gave up to find a solution for it!